# Simplify Vs FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, parallelization, parametric-functions

I performed an integral and received an extremely long answer. I tried running `FullSimplify` on the answer, and after 72 hours gave up. Does `FullSimplify[Simplify[expression]]` run faster than `FullSimplify[Expression]`? If not, is there any way to use parallel computing to speed up the process? Mathematica uses 14% of my CPU and only 1 of 6 cores.

```
Integrate[(((ϕ k11 + R k12 - ω^2 (ϕ m11 + R m12))^2 + (ϕ k21 +
         R k22 - ω^2 (ϕ m21 + 
           R m22))^2) E^(-0.5 (R/σ)^2))/((ω^4 ((ϕ m11 + 
          R m12)^2 + (ϕ m21 + 
          R m22)^2)) (σ (2 π)^0.5)), {R, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  k11 ∈ Reals && k21 ∈ Reals && k22 ∈ Reals && 
   m22 ∈ Reals && m21 ∈ Reals && 
   m11 ∈ Reals && ω ∈ Reals && ϕ ∈ 
    Reals && σ ∈ Reals && m11 > 0 && m22 > 0 && k11 > 0 && 
   k22 > 0 && σ > 0]
```

Comment: When the answer is very long, it is unlikely that (Full)Simplify will help. Sometimes you need to do some steps manually, in a controlled way, instead of fully relying on a computer. E.g., Simplify will not detect common subexpressions and express the result in terms of them. You need to understand the problem, know what they mean, and phrase the problem in terms of them from the beginning.

Comment: I'm performing an integral on a real domain, with real variables (written in the assumptions), and receive a complex answer, therefore I do not understand the answer, and since the output is about 3 pages long I really try to avoid using hand calculations.

Comment: Such an issue arises when e.g. elliptic integrals and functions are involved, however if some resonable transformation are prescribed manually then the result appears to be quite simple. One cannot suggest a valuable solution unless an integral is provided.

Comment: To be clear, no, it is not possible to parallelize this in a reasonable way.

Comment: the integral is ((a+bx)/(c+dx))^2*(exp(-(x/s)^2))dx, from plus to minus infinity

Comment: @MaayanGoodman please provide the complete expression you used as Mathematica code by editing your question and including it as formatted code.

Comment: The integrand is singular at `x = - c/d`.

Comment: @MarcoB The code is added to the question